# Exporting same DLL function under multiple names

Tags: delphi, winapi, dll, delphi-7, fastmm

I have made some functions in my DLL, like this:

```
procedure DoThis(A: PChar): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
f := TFileStreamCreate(A, fmCreate);
f.read()
f.free;
end;
```

then I exported it under 2 names:

```
export
  DoThis,
  DoThis name 'DoThat';
```

In most cases this "renaming" works. But in at least one case the renamed function "DoThat" does not read data from a real file but from the void. If I call DoThis on the same file- it works great.
I removed all memory leaks thanks to FastMM4 (converted the code to regular console app)

So the question is:

Is this "renaming" not a legal thing to do?

If it is legal- can I debug DLL with FastMM4 without changing it into a console app?

Comment: What you are describing did not happen unless you prove it. Don't paste fake code. Paste a real program, a complete program. Fake code is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: I can't just paste here over 200 kB of code. I am not looking for a solution to the problem but just an answer to the 2 questions.

Comment: What you post is a cutdown repro of the code. You only need 20-30 lines. The act of making that cutdown repro would convince you  that the problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe in the question is not consistent with reality.

> Is this "renaming" not a legal thing to do?

Exporting the same function under multiple names is perfectly legal. The problems you describe do not happen.

> Can I debug DLL with FastMM4 without changing
>   it into a console app?

Yes you can. Specify a host application in the Run parameters dialog and you can debug your DLL.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. The second doesn't work for me- the usual FastMM dialog boxes with memory leaks do not appear. But since I know it definitely is possible I'll dig further. Thank you, that information is all I needed!

Comment: FastMM leak reports are shown from a DLL